# Async in Android Studio

Tags: android, asynchronous

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qfKYL.png)

Hi everyone, I tried to insert an image from Internet to Android Studio using Async. But seem like some problem happened and I can not call the runOnUIThread to enable the function for Async. How can I fix it? Thank you so much.

Comment: Please move the code from an image to the question body

Comment: You should move hinh.setImageBitmap(Bmp); line to onPostExecute() method. Override onPostExecute() inside AsyncTask.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you want to use that runOnUiThread() inside onCreate() method..??
onCreate() will be called on ui thread only. There is no use to call runOnUiThread() inside onCreate() method.

If you want in some other place, that method start's with small letter. So type small 'r' instead of Capital 'R'.

Use below code :

```
  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

        }
    });
```

And you should not implement any UI related code inside doInBackground(). If you want to update UI after completion of doInBackground(), add those line of code inside onPostExecute().

Answer (score 0):

You do not need `runOnUIThread` on `AsyncTask`.

```
 private class LoadhinhtuInternet extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Bitmap> {

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
            InputStream stream = null;
            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (stream != null) {
                    try {
                        stream.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            super.onPostExecute(bitmap);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                hinh.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
  }
```

In `AsyncTask` the `onPostExecute` runs on the UI thread.